Not able to connect to db within the db container to take backup
I wanted to take a manual backup of the db but using the verbose flag I have discovered that I am not able to connect to the db running within the container,
root@5ebcf2a3efd4:~# mysqldump -uroot -psshh  -v  clinic_app_auth > clinic_app_auth.sql
-- Connecting to localhost...

in the above command I am inside the container but stuck at Connecting to localhost

Which setting are in the config used?   ( see: Configuring MariaDB for Remote Client Access, because it does not seem to listen to localhost )

Is this a docker exec shell or the docker run? There needs to be MariaDB running, then docker exec containername mariadb-dump ...... Also see MariaDB-backup
